# Trademark Infringement notice for usage of a dictionary word Jacuzzi in app - Google Play Store

Tags: trademark, innocent-infringement

I'm a 1-woman independent developer who made an app called Front Jacuzzi Back Corgi - or FJBC for short. Today, I received a trademark infringement notice from Jacuzzi.com

It's unexpectedly not from the App Store, but from Google Play.

> trademark_explain: Unauthorized use of the JACUZZI Trademark within
>   the App  that misleads the users into falsely believing that the
>   developer is a  manufacturer, licensee, or authorized user of Jacuzzi
>   Inc’s. trademarks, or  that Jacuzzi Inc. has endorsed or sponsored the
>   App and or its associated  websites, and any third party website.

My usage of jacuzzi seems to be the dictionary non-Jacuzzi.com branded version. Nothing in my app even remotely looks like things from jacuzzi.com ...

But, are there other conditions that I should be aware of?

Arguably, my app merely simulates the feel of a jacuzzi resort - and does not even include a jacuzzi. Technical people have criticized my water effects for not actually looking like a jacuzzi. The audio recording is actually not from a jacuzzi either.

Any advice is appreciated - esp on how to respond. Thank you

--

In trying to come up with a name to stick with, I've encountered a lot of dictionary words such as jet and jets that turn out to be trademarked? How would you suggest I make sure the re-name would be okay? Previously, I had searched to make sure Front Jacuzzi wasn't used as a name, but was not aware that jacuzzi had a trademark meaning beyond that defined in m-w.com

Answer (score 4):

Quit using the word Jacuzzi. That word is a brand name for a specific maker of hot tubs like Ford is for cars and not just a term for a hot tub.

This happens so much to them that they have a site devoted to it.
https://www.jacuzzi.com/baths/support/trademark-use/

Comment: It's a dictionary word - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Jacuzzi

Comment: That just means it is widely used. The word is still a brand name.

Comment: I read that and I don't fully understand it - does it mean add a ® each time the word jacuzzi is used?

Comment: If you use it in a sentence, yes. However they do not want you to use in the title, because it sounds like you are saying its part of their company. Just say hot tub.

Comment: Is using "jacuzzi" as a regular word not common enough for this to be a genericized trademark similar to "escalator"?

Answer (score 0):

Many trademarked terms are in dictionaries. Merriam-Webster lists "kodak" as a verb. Look at **how** dictionaries list a term:

- [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/jacuzzi)
- [The Cambtridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/jacuzzi)
- [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/jacuzzi)

All define "jacuzzi" as a brand name or trademark. Other dictionaries note that it is named for the inventor, who presumably left or sold his rights to the current company. I suspect that you will have a hard time establishing that there is a generic meaning for this term, since you are using it in exactly the sense for which there is trademark protection.

If you want to continue using this term, you would be wise to at least include a prominent statement that you are not affiliated with or authorized by Jacuzzi Inc in any way, and that "Jacuzzi" is a trademark of theirs, which you are using only to describe such a device.

However, if you can find and use a different term, such as "whirlpool" or "jet bath" you might be safer. Using the term as part of the name of your app is particularly likely to imply some sort of affiliation, and therefore to be trademark infringement.

You should consider consulting a lawyer with trademark expertise in your jurisdiction. Trademark laws and trademark protections very significantly by country.

Comment: Yes, use a different name.

Comment: Would Jet or Jets be subject to the same trademark law though? it seems there are various trademarks on jets...

Comment: It looks like Jetted Tub is also a trademark...

Comment: Whirlpool is a trademark too....?

Comment: @ina, yes but Whirlpool is a trademark for a different sort of thing -- as far as i know there is no tub with jkets under that name. Trademark protection is specific to the type of product.

Comment: @ina. Whirlpool is a generic dictionary word first, and a trademark second. They took an English word and trademarked it (in a specific domain). Jacuzzi is a trademark first. Any other usage derives from the trademark. https://law.stackexchange.com/a/40605/372.

Comment: i notice you did not list the m-w.com definition? i'm curious if m-w is typically not used?

Comment: @ina M-W is a major dictionary. I don't think it is the best, it is IMO too ready to defer to very recent usage. But I didn't list it because it was already listed in the question, so it would have been redundant. I wanted several that showed the trademark or brand-name status of the word, one way or the other.

Comment: is there such a thing as a de facto dictionary that's used with highest deference? there seems to be several dictionaries

Comment: @ina Not really. Different dictionaries are better for different purposes, and after that it can be a matter of opinion.  I would say that the Oxford English Dictionary is probably the closest that there is to an "official" dictionary, and is certainly best on word origins and etymology. But other people will favor other dictionaries.